# SqlAlchemy all() is not working

Tags: sqlalchemy

One of my queries in my web app is not working correctly.

```
session.query(GroupUserRelationship).filter(GroupUserRelationship.user_id == user.id).all()
```

and when I print the result, i get

```
[<DB.models.GroupUserRelationship object at 0x104fd2d90>]
```

How do I get an actual list of all the columns that match the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[all()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=all#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all) returns an list of [ objects ] which in your case looks to contain a single GroupUserRelationship.

If you know only a single object should be returned, instead of a list checkout either:
[one()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=all#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one)
or
[first()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=all#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first)